# GitHub Actions showing up in the wrong Workflow

Tags: github, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions

Our team recently switched to GitHub, and we set up some CICD flows using GitHub Actions. Now we have the problem, that certain actions are **showing up in the wrong workflow lists**.

If you check the below screenshot, you can see...

- The currently **selected workflow** is `Release CI`
- On the right hand side we can see the **triggered actions**...
- But some of these actions actually concern a **different workflow**, namely `Release 1.1. CI` (*marekd yellow*) - which also has it's own entry in the workflow list on the left (*marked green*).
- There is yet another kind of actions showing up (`Release 1.1 PR CI`), which also have their own workflow in the UI.

--> How comes? Am I misunderstanding the UI here?

[image]

---

In case this is important...

This is the start of the `Release CI` config:

```
name: Release CI

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'release'
```

This is the start of the `Release 1.1. CI` config:

```
name: Release 1.1 CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [release_1_1]
```

This is the start of the `Release 1.1 PR CI` config:

```
name: Release 1.1 PR CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [release_1_1]
```

Comment: do any of them run on pull request?

Comment: @xandermonkey, we have other pipelines running on PR, namely `Release 1.1 PR CI`, which _also_ shows up in the above list on the right.